# PHP if (isset($_POST['uname'])) not doing anything?

Tags: php, forms, isset

I have two pages. 1st page has two text forms like so:

```
<form name="NameForm">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "uname">
Location: <input type = "text" name = "ulocation">

<button type="button" onClick="MakeRequest()"">Save</button>
</form>
```

It pushes the information into page number two using javascript like so (note this is on the same page as the code above):

```
<script>
function MakeRequest()
{
// get values
var uname = document.NameForm.uname.value;
var ulocation = document.NameForm.ulocation.value;

// validation stuff here that detects browser

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
var url = "location.php?uname=" + uname + "&ulocation=" + ulocation;
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

So the problem is this, the php scripts on the page that does all server communication is not reading and storing the variables from this post request into my database.(my other get methods that view items in the database works fine)

```
if (isset($_POST['uname']))
{
    $name = $_POST['uname'];
$location = $_POST['ulocation']
}
```

then the query goes somehting like

```
//$table and the other undefined variables are the names of my table & columns
$query = "INSERT INTO $table ($tablename, $tablelocation) VALUES ('$name', '$location')";
```

Basically I'm trying to get that query to work. If i remove the If statement, it stores $name to the database but not $location.

EDIT:
I forgot to add

```
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: What you are doing is extremely insecure.  You are wide open to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: I'm just attempting to get this to work first!

Comment: ... and I'm just trying to prevent you from making a disastrous mistake.  Build things correctly from the start.  It doesn't take any extra time, and is worth doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a `GET`.
to send a `POST` try:

**[edited] perform the functions that order**

```
function XHR(){
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !=="undefined"){
        try{ return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e){}
    }
    if(typeof ActiveXObject !=="undefined"){
        try{ return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){}
        try{ return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){}
    }
    return false;
}

function MakeRequest()
{
    // get values
    var uname = document.NameForm.uname.value;
    var ulocation = document.NameForm.ulocation.value;

    // validation stuff here that detects browser

    var url = "location.php";

    xmlhttp = XHR();//Fixed
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");//Fixed
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "ERROR:"+xmlhttp.status;
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send("uname=" + uname + "&ulocation=" + ulocation);
}
```

Comment: Tried that now, but no results still. 
How can I attempt to debug it?

Comment: I edited the code, test if there is no result analize the browser console errors: http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console

Comment: had any result with the console's web browser?

Comment: First I get a GET which is the page, then [21:39:20.830] SyntaxError: syntax error @ line 29 which is if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {

Comment: when i submit the form i also receive --
[21:39:39.759] ReferenceError: MakeRequest is not defined @ WEBPAGELOCATION:1

Comment: To use this code you need to add xmlhttp.setHeader("content-type", "utf8"); or something like that, look it up.

Comment: I added it and it worked: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`. See I edited the answer, copy the code.

Comment: also added the `XHR function` inside `makeRequest function` so that each time you run `makeRequest` no conflicts. Watch how the code was.

Comment: Success! 
I assume XHR means XML Header Request?
I appreciate all ansers.

Comment: Actually it `XML Http Request`. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="NameForm">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "uname">
Location: <input type = "text" name = "ulocation">

<button type="button" onClick="MakeRequest()"">Save</button>
</form>
```

Your missing a form method. In your case you wish:

```
<form name='NameForm" method="POST">
```

If this does not resolve your issue, then download and use firebug for firefox or chrome console to debug javascript errors.

There will be no output of errors in JS to the text. You will need to use a debug console.

*perform an insert via html form*

I would modify your HTML to:

```
<form name="NameForm" method="POST">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "uname">
Location: <input type = "text" name = "ulocation">

<button type="button" onClick="MakeRequest()"">Save</button>
<input type='submit' name='SubmitForm' value='SUBMIT THIS FORM'>
</form>
```

Then my PHP code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['SubmitForm'])){
   $Name = $_POST['uname'];
   $Location = $_POST['ulocation'];
   // Perform validation for these inputs, check if empty, set correctly ETC

    $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($tablename, $tablelocation) VALUES ('$name', '$location')";
}
```

then call your Javascript function inside your PHP script; or perform an ajax/jquery call to run the insert without the need of a submit button

Comment: Doing this, i get a POST OK with the debugger but nothing in my database, i will try firebug now

Comment: Ok so i just debugged a little with firebug, and the JS seems to be wroking fine, it stores the variables corectly as well as send the information to the page that does the query..

Comment: have you performed an `echo $Name;` from your PHP?

Comment: I.E `echo $Name." Is Set via PHP";`

Comment: Yes, there is something similar in place but it does not display it at all,
with your edited code, the strings within the textbox dissapear and nothing happens edit: one second i missed something out in your update

Comment: Still nada- When i press submit it is sending the information to the other php page (i know because as soon as i remove the isset it echos it) However, That isset needs to be there else it runs other scripts

Comment: Put the php code all in the same code and it works like a charm, Does that mean I am going wrong with my JS?